# How does a close votes queue have over 9,000 questions in it while the edit queue is always limited at 150~

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

I have been editing various posts this morning to improve grammar, readability and overall improve the quality of questions and answers, however I keep coming across that the Edit Queue is full please try again in a few minutes.

So I head over to the [queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and to see what's up. Over 9,700 questions are in the "Close votes" section, yet suggested edits is less than 150.

Is there any reason as to why Close votes has such a massive queue yet you can still continue to flag, whereas edits are so very limited?

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416/165773)

Comment: [The general community position on the CVQ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBtpyeLxVkI)

Comment: You might consider not putting too much effort in fixing spelling or grammar if the post itself is understandable otherwise. You can leave this to people who can edit the posts directly and use your energy differently. This will also leave more space to important edits in the queue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The suggest edit queue has a cap because a suggested edit blocks further edits on the post. We wouldn't want to limit editing to 9000 posts at a time. By capping the queue, we can rate-limit suggested edits coming in and keep most of the site open to edits from people that can edit posts directly.

Close votes do not have such a downside, and expire automatically, so a cap there wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I didn't realise that the edit queue being full was based off the amount of active edits my account has. Ta

Comment: @Ian It's not, it's all suggested edits coming in from everyone combined. Of course, when you suggest a lot of edits, you risk clogging up the queue :-)

Comment: @Justastudent there is also a per-user rate limit. See [Rate limit suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Huh, today I learned. Thanks!